# How can I pass an ag-grid table in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have a page in which I generate in the back-end a table using the AG-GRID library, generating a file (js). This file once generated I call it from my front-end in which I use Handlebars. So far the code works correctly.

```
//BACKEND (I create a text string to generate the js file that creates the ag-grid table)

const list_membersJS = "var changePageSizeFunction; \n  function setPivotTable() {\nconst columnDefs = [\n{ headerName: 'Nombre', field: 'nombre', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'},\n{ headerName: 'Correo Electrónico', field: 'correo', cellRenderer: function (params) {var usuario = params.data.correo; return `<a target='_blank' href='mailto:${usuario}'>${usuario}</a>`;}},\n{ headerName: 'Empresa', field: 'empresa', filter: 'agSetColumnFilter'}];\nconst rowData = [" + txtrow + "];\nconst gridOptions = {\ncolumnDefs: columnDefs,\ndefaultColDef: {\nflex: 1,\nminWidth: 150,\nresizable: true,\nenableValue: true,\nenableRowGroup: true,\nsortable: true\n},\nanimateRows: true,\nrowData: rowData,\npagination: true,\npaginationPageSize: 15,\ndomLayout: 'autoHeight',\nenableSorting: true,\nenableFilter: true\n}\nconst eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');\nnew agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);\n agGrid.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('[TRIAL]_this_AG_Grid_Enterprise_key_( AG-043903 )_is_granted_for_evaluation_only___Use_in_production_is_not_permitted___Please_report_misuse_to_( legal@ag-grid.com )___For_help_with_purchasing_a_production_key_please_contact_( info@ag-grid.com )___All_Front-End_JavaScript_developers_working_on_the_application_would_need_to_be_licensed___This_key_will_deactivate_on_( 30 September 2023 )____[v2]_MTY5NjAyODQwMDAwMA==4a43d539f6521489ef3e796e6a5d1d09'); \n changePageSizeFunction = function () {\n  const pageSizeSelect = document.getElementById('pageSizeSelect');\n  const selectedPageSize = parseInt(pageSizeSelect.value, 10);\n\n  if (selectedPageSize === -1) {\n    // Si se selecciona \"Todos\", establecer un tamaño de página alto para mostrar todos los elementos.\n    gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(Number.MAX_VALUE);\n  } else {\n    gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(selectedPageSize);\n  }\n}; \n }"

await fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/../public/js/list_members.js', dataFile)


//FRONTEND

<script src="../js/list_members.js"></script> --}}
```

The problem I have is that if two users perform an action or load the page at the same time, the file is displayed.js with the data of the last user since the file.js is a static file.

I would like to see how I can generate the ag-grid table from my backend and that from route I can pass a variable with my ag-grid table already configured, so that in handlebars I can call the variable and that when loading the table is displayed with the data of each user.

Similarly, if there is a faster way to solve this problem, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ag-grid is a client-side library to add interactivity to data tables. Why not just send the data to your client as JSON using `fetch`, then render the data on the client? This way, you will not have concurrency issues at all since every client will be in charge of rendering its own instance of the table.

How to fetch data from the client using `fetch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Here is the example from ag-grid's quickstart, modified to use fetch:

```js
const columnDefs = [
  { field: "make" },
  { field: "model" },
  { field: "price" }
];

// Fetch the data, then setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Querying the data using fetch and promises
  fetch('/grid-data')
    // Deserializing the data we received
    .then(response => response.json())
    // We have our data now, we initialize our table
    .then(data => {
      const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
      new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, {
        columnDefs,
        rowData: data,
      });
    })
});
```

Basically, your "inline" javascript would be moved from a dynamic file being written on disk by Node.js and you would load your script in the browser using a `script` tag, just like you were.

What changes now is that you need to define a new endpoint in your Node server to serve this data as JSON.

```js
const app = express()

// Other express config stuff

app.get('/grid-data', (req, res) => {
  // This is our grid data. The properties of each object follows
  // our column definitions. Whatever extra will not be shown.
  const gridData = [
    {
      make: 'Honda',
      model: 'Civic',
      price: 9999.99
    }
  ];

  // Sending the data to the client as JSON
  res.json(gridData);
})
```

Comment: You're right, but in that case how can I define this? Would I have a file.js base in which I have the basic parameters of the table and the data I get from the json that I send to the client through route?

Can you explain a little more about how I can solve this? since I'm somewhat blocked...

Comment: You are correct. You would define a static client javascript file (like the one I included as an example in the answer) and you would serve your data on a separate route on your NodeJS server.

Your handlebar page can load the static script on the client using the `<script src="...">` tag, just like you doing previously. This way, the code being executed is separate from the data that feeds into the code.

Comment: I amended my response to give you a better overview of the server code as well

Comment: Thank you, I have modified my code and it works correctly. A query, this works well for me only in the firefox browser, but if I use edge or chrome it does not work... Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? The fetch API is compatible across browser. You can see error messages in the browser dev console by pressing F12 on your page.

Comment: **Problem:** I get the following error when creating a map with Bing Maps:
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (FaenaMaps.js:9:17)

**My Code:**
const map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
credentials: 'secret_key',
center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data.latitudemap, data.longitudemap),
mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
zoom: 15
});

What could be causing this error?I verified that the API key is correct.

Comment: This new problem seems to be unrelated to this question. I'm no expert with Bing Maps, but somebody in the community can probably help you if you open a new question.